# How to play and audio and Run Webcam Simultaneouly using Pydub and OpenCV Libraries?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to play an audio file and Run my Webcam both Simultaneouly using Pydub and OpenCV in my code. But, when I run the code, the audio plays first but, the webcam doesn't run in the While Loop. This is the code for the same:-

```
import cv2 as cv
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# Initiate the Webcam

camera = cv.VideoCapture(0)

# Audio

audio_src = 'song.mp3'

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_src)

play(song)

while True:

    ret_val, frame = camera.read()

    if (ret_val is True):
    
        cv.imshow('Frame', frame)

    key = cv.waitKey(1)
    if (key == 27):
        break

camera.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any suggestions on how can I use pydub to play Audio and run Wecam Simulataneously? Or any other module for playing Audio? Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not related to opencv

use a some library which plays sound background

like

https://github.com/cheofusi/just_playback